# Error in using my own jar file

Tags: jakarta-ee

I have created one java application which has some API's. I exported this project into a .jar file and used this .jar file into my other project. The jar is getting imported  and also I can access the classes. But when I run the project I get

****HTTP Status 500 - Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/java/client/RestClient/RestClient****

but while my import statement :
**import com.java.client.RestClient.RestClient;**

is not showing any error.

**My jar is without Main Method.**
Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Maybe you have it correctly configured at compile time, but at run time, your lib has not been set in the classpath

Comment: The exception is rather self-explaining: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/java/client/RestClient/RestClient` This particular class is missing in the runtime classpath. This is apparently a dependency of your own JAR. That you got your JAR successfully to compile just meand that it was present in compiletime classpath. You just need to make sure that it's also present in runtime classpath.